# How can I tell when Finder is done searching?

Tags: finder

I don't see any progress indicator, and the title of the window says:

```
Searching "[Directory]"
```

Is there supposed to be something that happens to let me know when the search is complete?  On some large directories (tens of thousands of files in hundreds of sub-directories) I know the search *isn't* complete, because it hasn't found files that I know are there, and I usually give up before it finds them.  So on a directory with less files it is rather concerning to see no indication if the search is done yet or not, especially when nothing has been found that I *hope* will be found, but am not sure if will.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can. Turn on the status bar: View > Show Status Bar.

There you can see whether the Mac is searching.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like this is a new feature in Mavericks, it works on my 10.9 box, but not another box running 10.8.5.

Comment: Don't seems to be working on High Sierra 10.13.6